# tf tree for viso2

Tags: ros-fuerte, viso2-ros, static-transform-publisher, viso2, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up a tf tree to use with viso2 to reconstruct point clouds, but I'm running into a lot of issues.  Right now I'm just trying to set up a chain of dummy static transforms in order to get something working (i.e., I know the reconstruction will be bad because the transforms are arbitrary/incorrect, but I just want to see that I can get data displayed).

I've tried to set up a bunch of static transforms as follows, with the intent of creating the tf tree:

map -> odom -> base_link -> caodom -> camera_optical_frame

->base_link -> odom_combined -> base_footprint

(base_link is the parent of both caodom and odom_combined frames)

```
<launch>

  <arg name="simtime" value="true" />

  <!-- Get name of bagfile (passed in to roslaunch as arg) -->
  <!--  <arg name="bagfile" />-->

  <!-- Play bag file. -->
  <!-- not working right now <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="$(find stereo_data)/$(arg bagfile).bag" />-->
  <!--  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="SCRIPPS.bag" />-->
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="$(find stereo_data)/SCRIPPS.bag --clock" />


  <!-- Publish transforms -->

  <!-- Transform from camera odom frame to camera_optical_frame -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="caodom_to_camera_optical_frame" args="0 0 0 0.1 0.1 0.1 /caodom /camera_optical_frame 100 --clock">
    <param name="queue_size" value="50" />
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
  </node>

  <!-- Transform from base_link to caodom -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_caodom" args="0 0 0 0.1 0.1 0.1 /base_link /caodom 100 --clock">
    <param name="queue_size" value="50" />
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
  </node>

  <!-- Transform from base_link to odom_combined -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_odom_combined" args="0 0 0 0.1 0.1 0.1 /base_link /odom_combined 100 --clock">
    <param name="queue_size" value="50" />
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
  </node>

  <!-- Transform from odom_combined to base_footprint -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_combined_to_base_footprint" args="0 0 0 0.1 0.1 0.1 /odom_combined /base_footprint 100 --clock">
    <param name="queue_size" value="50" />
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
  </node>



  <!-- Debayer and rectify images -->
  <group ns="stereo/left">
    <node pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" name="image_proc_left">
      <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
    </node>  
  </group>

  <group ns="stereo/right">
    <node pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" name="image_proc_right">
      <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
    </node>
  </group>

  <!-- Visual odometry node -->
  <node pkg="viso2_ros" type="stereo_odometer" name="vo2" 
      args="stereo:=stereo image:=image_rect _odom_frame_id:=/odom_combined _base_link_frame_id:=/base_footprint _publish_tf:=true">
    <param name="approximate_sync" value="true" />
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
  </node>

  <!-- Compute disparities for images -->
  <node pkg="elas_ros" type="elas_ros" name="elas" args="stereo:=stereo image:=image_rect_color" respawn="true">
    <param name="approximate_sync" value="true" />
    <param name="queue_size" value="10" />
    <param name="/use_sim_type" value="simtime" />
  </node>

  <!-- Compute 3D point clouds from disparities -->
  <node pkg="elas_ros" type="pc_construction" name="elas_pc" 
    args="frame_data:=/elas/frame_data pose:=/vo2/pose base_frame_id:=/odom_combined pose_frame_id:=/base_footprint">
      <param name="approximate_sync" value="true" />
      <param name="queue_size" value="10" />
      <param name="/use_sim_time" value="simtime" />
  </node>

  <!-- View debayered/rectified images -->
  <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="image_view_left" args="image:=stereo/left/image_rect_color" />
  <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="image_view_right" args="image:=stereo/right/image_rect_color" />

  <!-- View computed disparity maps -->
  <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="image_view" args="image:=/elas/disparity" />

  <!-- Launch Rviz -->
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz">
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
  </node>


</launch>
```

However, this results in the following tf tree:

[image: image description]

I am very confused about what's going on.   First of all, can you even do this with static transforms or have I missed something?  It makes sense to me that you could publish a static transform between two clearly static reference frames (i.e., fixed cameras on a robot) but maybe I am wrong.  Also, why does it seem to think 100 (the broadcast rate) is a child frame?  I have tried a million different things and am totally confused.

Also, at one point I used this same launch file on a different computer and the tf tree was connected properly.  I have since reinstalled Ubuntu/ROS and have the same issue.  I'm using ROS fuerte.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63408/tf-tree-for-viso2/) by [antonella](https://answers.ros.org/users/2820/antonella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-05-24**:
Your posted launch file is invalid. Please post a complete working example.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-05-24**:
What are you trying to achieve by setting the parameter `/use_sim_time` four times to `"simtime"`? If you are playing back a bagfile using `rosbag play --clock ...` and want the system to use the simulated time you'll have to set `/use_sim_time` (only once) to `"true"`.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-05-24**:
If a frame in your tree is called `/100` that's an indicator that you ran static_transform_publisher with wrong arguments. Carefully count them! See `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher` (without arguments) for examples.

**Comment by [antonella](https://answers.ros.org/users/2820/antonella/) on 2013-05-26**:
I updated the question with the complete launch file. simtime is a variable that is set to true at the beginning of the file. I was under the impression that any node needing to use the use_sim_time parameter had to have that parameter set, which is why it's set for every node.

**Comment by [antonella](https://answers.ros.org/users/2820/antonella/) on 2013-05-26**:
I have read how `static_transform_publisher works`, and I only see 6 arguments for `x y z yaw pitch roll`.  This is part of the reason I'm stumped. When I try adding a seventh argument to use quaternions (`x y z qx qy qz qw`) I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it working. I was setting the `--clock` flag for each `static_transform_publisher` node, which was what was causing the `/100` frame and also the incorrect number of arguments (I was doing this because I read somewhere that setting --clock was necessary when running `static_transform_publisher` if rosbag play was using --clock but I guess that's not the case). Everything is working now, and now the tree is correct:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [antonella](https://answers.ros.org/users/2820/antonella/) with karma: 259 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1